# Random <embed> tag being displayed strictly in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, embed

I am building a website using (so far) html/css/jQuery. It looks great in Chrome, but has some display issues in Firefox im working on.

The main one, which baffles me, is a completely random  tag being displayed immediately following my  tag, but it only appears in Firefox. The code (shown below) displays a white square in the upper-left corner of the page and shows when I view the source, but is not coded into the actual html page.

Here is the code firefox

```
<embed id="munqql" type="application/x-firefox-plg" style="height: 10px; width:10px; display:block;"> … </embed>
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Edit: I tried updating my css file to hide #munqql, and this did not work. Nor does any style affect the element.

Comment: Is it there if you open firefox in private browsing mode(with all extensions turned off)? I bet it's a broken toolbar.

Comment: Hmm, somehow an extension called "mozilla firefox munqql plugin 8.2.13.1104" is installed. There is no option to uninstall and google returns no results. What the hell is that thing? Going to uninstall Firefox & reinstall.

I have another firefox related issue I'd like to run by you regarding webfonts. I am using custom fonts for my website, and they display fine in Chrome. In firefox, they only display if I access my website with www. in front - if I access it via http://url.com or url.com the fonts fail to load and a default font is used. Any idea, since your toolbar solution was spot on :)

Comment: I have no idea, i've never encountered that. I rarely use firefox other than for cross-browser testing.